# How to write a perfect hash function for 36 strings?

Tags: java, math, hashtable, hash-function, cryptographic-hash-function

Using the numbers 0-5 I need to write a perfect has function for 36 Student ID Strings with six characters and 3 integers (e.g. BYPLOK120).

**The hash function looks something like as follows:**

```
String [] studentID = ...
```

is 36 unique Strings in the format (xxx/yyy/zzz) where x and y are three letters from the students last and first names, respectively. z are 3 random numbers.

```
int hashTableSize = 37;`

int [] hashValue = new int[9];`

int [] weights = {1,0,5,4,3,2,5,1,2};
```

Weights is 9 numbers between 0-5. THIS IS THE PART I NEED TO FIGURE OUT - there are about 2 million combinations (5^9) and less than 10 will give you a perfect hash function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hashTableSize; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < studentID[I].length; j++)
       hashVal[i] += ( studentID[i].charAt(j) * weight[j] ) % hashTableSize;
```

**I need the hash value of each string in the array to be unique (i.e. there are no collisions when inserting)**

I had duplicate hash values as I could not find the unique array of weight integers.

Comment: How long does it take to try one set of weights?  If sufficiently short, you can brute-force it.

Comment: Is there some principle talked about in class which would help you divine what those 9 numbers are, or are you just supposed to have the clairvoyance to figure out what that principle is?

Comment: they reckon were mathemagicians

Comment: @RobertHarvey ^^

Comment: @passer-by how?

Comment: Generate the first possibility for the weights[] array.  Use it to hash all student info - you can stop on the first collision.  If no collision, you're done.  Otherwise generate the next possibility for weights[] and try again.  Repeat until you find a value with no collisions.

Comment: The possibilities for weights , are just 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 then 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 then ... 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 etc.  It's just counting in a funny format. I'd be tempted to regard it as a single integer that I'd then split into base-6 digits (use Integer.toString(N, 6)), this makes the "generate next" straightforward.